# Python Sendgrid send email with all extension file attachment django

Tags: python, django, sendgrid-api-v3

I want to send an email with an attachment using SendGrid API with all extensions in Django. Here is my code for mail sending.

`views.py`

```
def submitTicket(request):
try:
    if request.method == 'POST':
        name = request.POST.get('name')
        email = request.POST.get('email')
        subject = request.POST.get('subject')
        comment = request.POST.get('comment')
        atchfile = request.FILES['fileinput']
        allinfo =  " Name : " + name + "\n E-Mail : " + email + "\n Comment : " + comment
        recipients_list = ['abc@gmail.com']
        if allinfo:
            message = Mail(from_email='xxx@gmail.com',
                                        to_emails=recipients_list,
                                        subject=subject, 
                                        html_content=allinfo)

            with atchfile.open() as f:
                data = f.read()
                f.close() 
            encoded_file = base64.b64encode(data).decode()
            attachedFile = Attachment(
                FileContent(encoded_file),
                FileName(atchfile.name),
                FileType(atchfile.content_type),
                Disposition('attachment')
            )            
            message.attachment = attachedFile               
            sg = SendGridAPIClient('0000000000000000000000000000000')
            sg.send(message)
           
            return HttpResponseRedirect('submitTicket')
except Exception as e:
    print("Exception = ", e)
    return render(request, 'submitTicket.html')
```

I am getting below error while trying to perform this.

`TypeError at /submitTicket expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not InMemoryUploadedFile`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 attachedFile = Attachment(
                    FileContent(encoded_file),
                    FileName(atchfile.name),
                    FileType(atchfile.content_type),
                    Disposition('attachment')
                )
```

Try this.

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue is that the `open` method does not take an [`InMemoryUploadedFile`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/_modules/django/core/files/uploadedfile/) as an argument. It normally expects a path to open.

However, because your `atchfile` is an `InMemoryUploadedFile` which inherits from [`File`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/files/file/) you can actually call `open` on the file itself. So I think you can do this instead:

```py
            with atchfile.open() as f:
                data = f.read()
                f.close()
```

Comment: @phinash, It is working for the file open now. but while sending `sg.send(message)` it throws type error = `TypeError at /submitTicket   
Object of type InMemoryUploadedFile is not JSON serializable`

Comment: can you please help me with this?

Comment: Can you update your question with the current code you are using?

Comment: I have updated my question can you please check.

Comment: The issue might be that you are passing `atchfile` to `FileName`, `FileType` and `Disposition`. Those classes expect the argument to be a string (or something serializable) and you are passing an `InMemoryUploadedFile`. Take a look at the [`InMemoryUploadedFile`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/_modules/django/core/files/uploadedfile/) class  and the [File class](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/files/file/) that it inherits from to find the right properties to use here.

Comment: I have updated my code as per your comment, Now Attachment is working, and Mail is sending properly with the attachment, but with that getting exceptions like `I/O operation on closed file.` @philnash

Comment: What line is that exception thrown on?

Comment: I got the solution, It is not related to this code. Thank you for the help.

Comment: Excellent news! If this did help you solve the question, would you mind marking it as correct so that others can see that it helped? Thanks!